# No internet access after upgrading to lubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, lubuntu, internet, dns

I have upgraded my lubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04 and then I have no access to internet even though my laptop is connected to wifi.
I have tried to set dns in `/etc/resolv.conf` but to no avail.

Some strange thing I have encountered is that after rebooting if I try to `ping 8.8.8.8` it successfully do so but as soon as I try something else like opening firefox and entering a website or trying to apt update the ping process stops and all the packets get failed.

I have tried every similar question on askubuntu but nothing.

**Update1**: ip route output

```
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.199 metric 600
```

**Update 2**:
ifconfig -a when ping is working:
[ifconfig ping working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF9CQ.jpg)

ifconfig -a when ping is **not** working:
[ifconfig ping **not** working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATGXi.jpg)

netstat -rnv in both states (they're the same):
[Netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPsjE.jpg)

**Update 3**
[Device status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGLu4.jpg)

[Wifi list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCBzl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a little strange ... but anyway do the basics as follows;

-- Check what do you have

```
sudo nmcli device  status
```

-- Your wifi ap should be visible here

```
sudo nmcli device  wifi list
```

-- Rescan if your ap doesnt appear

```
sudo nmcli device  wifi rescan
```

-- Connect to your wifi

```
sudo nmcli device wifi connect your_wifi_name   password   your_password
```

-- You should see status connected below

```
sudo nmcli device  status
```

Post the output of the first two commands if you are stuck.
All the best ya.

Comment: But I am connected to the wifi. The problem is I cannot reach to the internet

Comment: Post the output of the first two commands if you are stuck. Based on that, i would delete and recreate what is necessary.

Comment: Sorry I was away. I updated the post.

Comment: Hi @MehranMirshekaran - Based on your screenshots,  delete all ( except lo ), reboot and recreate what you need.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334487/major-bug-with-ubuntu-networkmanager/1337572#1337572

Comment: using lubuntu here. I was already connected to the Wifi, no ifconfig, no net-tools I couldn't do anything. Finally I followed line by line and it did the trick. Probably reconnecting to Wifi using cli is what did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a reason why the ping of an address like 8.8.8.8 would be affected by a dns lookup in a browser or apt, they should not affect the routing.  Can you post the output of your routes and network adapter configs whilst the ping is working and again when it stops?

```
ifconfig -a
netstat -rnv
```

that might shed some light on where the problem is.

Comment: This might help too: [link][https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334585/internet-issues-system-wide-after-21-04]

Comment: I added the outputs. Since I don't have enough points I cannot post images here :)

Comment: By the way I cannot ping my default gateway which is: 192.168.43.1. I've added the ip route output in the first update of the post

Comment: and in the recovery mode (terminal) by just setting dns in resolv.conf I can connect to internet.

Comment: Those look fine, seems more like a driver issue for your wifi card.  have a look at messages sudo dmesg -T see if there is anything in there about the hardware.  The firewall is off ins't it?  sudo ufw status

Comment: Yes firewall is off. I filtered the log for wlp3s0 and didn't find anything wrong. Just it was renamed from wlan0 to wlp3s0. Should I search differently?

Comment: I think this answer can help me: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024304/ubuntu-server-16-04-cant-ping-outside-ips-or-domains-or-do-updates) but I don't know what is the equivalent of /etc/network/interfaces in lubuntu 21.04

Comment: The issue in that link was that the gateway wasn't on the same network, yours is on the same network.    I think your system may use files in /etc/netplan to configure the interface, but it all seems to be configured correctly.  I would read the dmesg output and look for any strange messages.  Filtering for the wifi by wlps30 might not show what you are looking for.  I'm sorry but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes but I can't ping the default gateway. Thank you, I will read the dmesg output thoroughly then.

Comment: Please look at the link I posted earlier, that seems to be very similar to your issue, the wifi card was renaming itself and the log files contained error messages relating to wifi, he lost connection after random intervals too.  What is the default gateway for other computers on your network,  Can any of them ping your ubuntu host and the 192.168.43.1 address?  Your network address 192.168.43.0 is unusual perhaps the router isn't pingable at 192.168.43.1?

Comment: Sorry I was away. The default gateway is the same on other devices: `192.168.43.1`. They cannot ping my lubuntu but they can ping `192.168.43.1`.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04 I started getting this error from commands such as ping when trying to resolve hostnames:

```
Temporary failure in name resolution
```

However, I could still ping IP address. Strange thing is it was working okay for a little while but after a couple hours the errors showed up. Guess it was due to a timeout.

I tried a bunch of things so I'm not 100% which one fixed it but here are the last things I tried before it started working, I suspect it's one or both.

Check if your resolve.conf file is a real file or symlink:

```
ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
```

Mine was a real file so I changed it to a symlink and restarted resolved

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo service systemd-resolved restart
```

If that doesn't fix it try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/810636/how-to-manage-dns-in-networkmanager-via-console-nmcli