# Internet connection not working after updating nvidia drivers on kubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, internet

I recently did a fresh install of Kubuntu 21.10 and everything has worked fine for weeks. Yesterday the second monitor suddenly was not recognized anymore, so I tried to update the nvidia drivers. It turned out that the monitor was just not "enabled" in the display configuration panel in system settings (it was enabled first, but then it decided to disable itself for unknown reasons), however the display is now working, but I cannot access the internet anymore. The only thing I did was to update the recommended nvidia drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`, but I don't see how this could have broken my access to the internet.
I am using wired connection, and the network panel says I am connected. But I cannot navigate in Safari or download updates.
Please consider I am a relatively newbie in Linux and I have no clue what information to put here to help you better understand the problem.
I cannot find similar problems in the web. The only thing that I have tried so far is this (as suggested here: [No internet access after upgrading to lubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336006/no-internet-access-after-upgrading-to-lubuntu-21-04)):

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo service systemd-resolved restart
```

But it did not solved the problem.
Many thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: You might have installed a faulty network driver. `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` does not only install or update your graphics card driver. I don't use ubuntu but I remember that there was something called 'drivers ...'. Do you find anything called like that?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found "additional drivers", but only contains graphics drivers. How can I fix  a faulty network driver?

Comment: What's your network card's name? If you don't know how to find it out just google it. The name of the card is important information.

Comment: This is the output of lspci | grep - I net: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (Rev 05). Other information are: Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I217-LM; Kernel driver in use: e1000e; Kernel modules: e1000e.

Comment: In a deleted comment the OP wrote "Actually I did not. I opted for a fresh install of the OS."